# how to call a JS function on a asp:LinkButton click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this JS function that loads whenever the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        <asp:Literal ID="LiteralGraph01" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal ID="LiteralGraph_ft01" runat="server"></asp:Literal>


</script>
```

How can I invoke this function from a asp:LinkButton click? The link button is called filtroCombinado:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="filtroCombinado" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Standard way is `<asp:LinkButton ... OnClientClick="myFunc()" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<asp:LinkButton...` is rendered as an anchor (`<a href=...`). If you want to run some JS `onload` **and** `onclick` do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function myFunc () {//nobody blames you when you name the function
    <asp:Literal ID="LiteralGraph01" runat="server">some data I fill in from server (and replace this text)</asp:Literal>
    <asp:Literal ID="LiteralGraph_ft01" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    return false; //avoid sending request to the server
}//close the function
</script>
...
//do something before sending request to the server
<asp:LinkButton ID="filtroCombinado" runat="server" OnClientClick="return myFunc();"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       var onLoadFunction = function () {
            <asp:Literal ID="LiteralGraph01" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal ID="LiteralGraph_ft01" runat="server"></asp:Literal>


    </script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="filtroCombinado" runat="server" onClientClick="onLoadFunction()"></asp:LinkButton>
```